# What's wrong with these definitions of seq/pseq?

Tags: haskell, computer-science

There is a widespread opinion that seq/pseq functions are impossible to define in standard Haskell without extensions or primitive operations. But what is the difference between the behaviour of the following functions (defined using only standard Haskell 98/2010) and their real counterparts?

```
data Seq a b = Seq !a !b
seq a b = case Seq a b of
    Seq _ x -> x

data PSeq a b = PSeq !a b
pseq a b = case PSeq a b of
    PSeq _ x -> x
```

For example, it's easy to check that this definition satisfies

```
seq ⊥ x = ⊥
```

Some other simple experiments show no difference between these versions of seq/pseq and the real ones. So what's wrong?

Comment: There's probably nothing wrong. But in the Report, the behavior of strict fields is given in terms of `seq`. Gotta have one or the other as primitive, and it doesn't matter much which, but people generally think of `seq` as being the primitive one and strict fields as the derived one. You could probably define `seq` in terms of `($!)`, too, but it would suffer from the same complaint.

Comment: Thank you! The report definitely says that an application of a data constructor with strict fields is defined in terms of `$!` so my definitions use `seq` implicitly.

Comment: @DanielWagner That should probably be an answer

Comment: The built-in `pseq` and `seq` don't differ semantically.  Similarly, your `pseq` and `seq` don't differ semantically. There is nothing that guarantees that your definition of `pseq` will provide the *operational* guarantees that the built-in definition provides. I doubt it does in general even with the current GHC, and, of course, even if it does now, it may not in the future.